# How to install open source (core) Kendo UI via npm?

Tags: kendo-ui

Kendo UI's core version is open source. Instructions say to install Kendo UI using something like this:

```
npm install -g appbuilder
```

However, I'm not sure which version of Kendo UI that is--commercial or open source.

How do I install just the open source Kendo UI core product?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's pretty obvious:

```
# sudo may be optional
$ sudo npm install -g kendo-ui-core
```